# CakePHP: Global Redirect

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

In some parts of the application, a user can do some bad things by changing a URL. For example, let's say they'd change the request for an edit.

http://website.com/edit/4000

But they do not own post 4000, the only way they could have gotten there is through URL manipulation.

In these cases, I want to simply redirect them to the home page. However, if I trigger one of these catches, I want to display myself a message. (so it's not just a matter of a simple redirect)

I put this in the bootstrap.

```
function security_redirect ($msg) {
    if ((not_an_admin) == 1) {
       $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'site', 'action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        die($msg);
    }
}
```

I get the error message:

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

When I perform:

```
security_redirect("Tried to edit a post that isn't yours!");
```

What can I do? What am I doing wrong? I don't see why it's not considered to be inside an object... but maybe it's obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably best to not use a global method for this, but to throw an exception in those situations; read this part of the manual [Built in Exceptions for CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions-for-cakephp)

For example;

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

    public function edit ($id)
    {
        if (user isn't allowed to edit this post) {
            throw new ForbiddenException('You are not allowed to edit this post');
        }
    }

}
```

This is a better approach than using `die()` because Exceptions can be tested in unit testing and it will be handled by the CakePHP error handler, which will output an error page that can be styled as well

### extra example

Setting feedback messages inside your App can be done via [`SessionComponent::setFlash()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#creating-notification-messages)

To perform a redirect inside a controller and output a message, and have that function (method) available to all Controllers inside your App use something like this;

app/Controller/AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller
{    
    protected function security_redirect ($msg)
    {
        if ((not_an_admin) == 1) {
            // optionally, set 'flash' message
            $this->Session->setFlash($msg);
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'site', 'action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            throw new ForbiddenException($msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside other controllers, you can access this method like this;

```
class PostsController extends AppController
{    
    public function edit ($id)
    {
        if (/* user isn't allowed to edit this post */) {
            return $this->security_redirect('You are not allowed to edit this post');
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I will eventually want to do more than just throw exceptions in the future; I may want to write to a table (for example) to record the potential hack attempt. The reason I want global is to have that all in one place, rather than a bunch of exceptions everywhere. Very handy exceptions, though.

Comment: You can always put such logic inside `AppController::beforeFilter()` or another method inside your `AppController` so that any controller that extends the AppController can use that method?

Comment: I put it in and unfortunately still get the $this issue.

Comment: Well, you cannot put a function just inside your bootstrap.php, The function should be a *method* of your `AppController`. CakePHP uses [OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) (have you worked with object-oriented programming before?)

Comment: Perfect! I understand now. I've worked with OOP, but have a hard time applying my knowledge of it to CakePHP. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your project!